# Reducing repetition in sudoers file

Tags: sudo, wildcards, services, systemctl

I have a sudoers file, that allows a user to run sudo commands without a password (mostly to manage specific services). I would like to drastically reduce repetition throughout the config:

Here's a simple version:

```
Cmd_Alias NGINX = \
    /bin/systemctl start nginx, \
    /bin/systemctl stop nginx, \
    /bin/systemctl restart nginx, \
    /bin/systemctl reload nginx, \
    /bin/systemctl status nginx

# glob php version, to save this breaking on version changes
Cmd_Alias PHP = \
    /bin/systemctl start php[0-9].[0-9]-fpm, \
    /bin/systemctl stop php[0-9].[0-9]-fpm, \
    /bin/systemctl restart php[0-9].[0-9]-fpm, \
    /bin/systemctl reload php[0-9].[0-9]-fpm, \
    /bin/systemctl status php[0-9].[0-9]-fpm

...

username ALL = NOPASSWD: NGINX
username ALL = NOPASSWD: PHP

...
```

The real version has several specified services that all follow that same formatting. So, ideally, what would be better would be something like:

```
Cmd_Alias SERVICES = \
    /bin/systemctl {start,stop,restart,reload,status} {nginx,php[0-9].[0-9]-fpm,foo,bar,alice,bob}

username ALL = NOPASSWD: SERVICES
```

But it doesn't appear brace expansion is allowed. I get a syntax error about the commas, whether they're escaped or not.

So I checked `man sudoers` and it mentions basic forms of wildcards/globbing is possible (which works great for globbing the PHP version, as above):

```
Wildcards
     sudo allows shell-style wildcards (aka meta or glob characters) to be used in host names, path names, and command line arguments in
     the sudoers file.  Wildcard matching is done via the glob(3) and fnmatch(3) functions as specified by IEEE Std 1003.1 (“POSIX.1”).

     *         Matches any set of zero or more characters (including white space).

     ?         Matches any single character (including white space).

     [...]     Matches any character in the specified range.

     [!...]    Matches any character not in the specified range.

     \x        For any character ‘x’, evaluates to ‘x’.  This is used to escape special characters such as: ‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[’, and ‘]’.
```

but is it possible to reduce repetition using some other means? Variables maybe? An alias method I'm unaware of?

It'd be preferable that the expected user input still obtains the desired result, i.e. `sudo systemctl status whatever` rather than parsing user input with a script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use POSIX extended regular expressions in sudo version
[1.9.10](https://www.sudo.ws/posts/2022/03/sudo-1.9.10-using-regular-expressions-in-the-sudoers-file/)
onwards. The expression is delimited by `^` and `$`. (It cannot match command and arguments combined in a single regex). For example, (untested):

```
Cmd_Alias SERVICES = \
 /bin/systemctl ^(start|stop|restart|reload|status) +(nginx|php[0-9]\.[0-9]-fpm)$
```

See the latest [man page](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/#Regular_expressions).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I get syntax error with that too, but I'm guessing that's because the `sudo` version on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS that I'm using is 1.9.9 and not 1.9.10. I'll wait for the update before revisiting. :) Thanks!